# Create custom data type like integer, byte, double etc

Tags: delphi, types

For example: I want to make a Lightness Data Type for TColor which is a range of integers 0..240

I know `byte` is 0..255

But I'd like to have my own `Light` Data Type 0..240

Can someone show me how to achieve that?

I have this code:

```
type
  Light = record
  strict private
    FLight: 0..240;
  public
    class operator Explicit(const Value: Byte): Light;
  end;
implementation

{ Light }

class operator Light.Explicit(const Value: Byte): Light;
begin
  Result.FLight := Value;
end;
```

Does my code have any issues?

Comment: This depends on your precise requirements: Which properties should the type have? How should you create/use values of this type? How should they be converted to other types? Should such values have member functions? And so on. But the simplest solution (other than using a `Byte`) is `type
  TLightness = 0..240;` Regarding your solution, it is clearly missing a way to *read* the value!

Comment: Called subrange types in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Subrange_Types

Comment: This is off topic here since you are asking for a code review

Comment: It's missing the leading "T" customary for type declarations. You might want to check in the assignment operator that the value assigned is within the allowed range and if not raise an exception with a meaningful error message. And as @AndreasRejbrand already mentioned: You probably want to read the value too.

Comment: Thank you all for your respectful and helpful comments, my goal is to learn how to create my own custom datatype in Delphi, this code above is just a copy-paste from Mr: @DavidHeffernan code with my stupid edit on it (sorry Mr.:David) I take it from somewhere in this Respected site, I came to a conclusion
I see I need to know a lot of basics to get to the above question level, sorry for my bad English

Comment: use `type TLight=0..240` use TLight instead of byte.